# Compare fields in two files and print to another in shell

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Please help me with the below. I want to print values in 3rd file in shell scripting

Formatting of files should as per below one
a_file - col1  col2  col3
b_file - col1  col2

. a_file - col1  col2  col3
1                     P                         I
1                     1Q                        JI

.b_file
1 I

How to compare 1st field and 3rd field of a_file to 1st and 2nd fields of b_file? Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Print what values? And what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i understand your question correctly, the simplest way is to read both files line by line, compare specified columns and write customized output to the 3rd file.

```
 # read 3 columns from file descriptor 11 and two columns from file descriptor 12
 while read -u 11 acol1 acol2 acol3 && read -u 12 bcol1 bcol2; do
    # do comparisions betweencolumns
    if [ $acol1 = $bcol1 -a $acol3 = $bcol2 ]; then
       echo Comparision true
       # print values in 3rd file in shell scripting
       echo $acol1 $bcol1 $acol3 $bcol2 >>3rd_file
    else
       echo Comparision false
    fi
  # bind a_file to 11 file descriptor, and b_file to 12 file descriptor
  done 11<a_file 12<b_file
```